# How do I reconcile (what I see as) an apparent difference in the frame dragging formula used for Gravity Probe-B versus Lageos?

Tags: general-relativity, frame-dragging

The frame dragging impact above the north pole is given at [NASA's Gravity Probe-B website](https://einstein.stanford.edu/highlights/status1.html) as:

$$\Omega = \frac{GI\omega}{c^2r^3}.$$

That is, when the satellite is above the pole, it rotates with the Earth at this speed, as measured by the  rotation of a gyroscope about the north-south axis of the planet.

Yet the precession of the LAGEOS satellite is given in [places](https://adsabs.harvard.edu/full/1987CeMec..40...19C) as (neglecting the small eccentricity):

$$\Omega = \frac{2GI\omega}{c^2r^3}.$$

This is the speed at which the entire circular orbital path rotates.  Also, I note that the orbital inclination (which is about 70 degrees for Lageos) doesn't seem to impact the precession, or at least, there doesn't seem to be a place in the equation to account for it.

I appreciate any thoughts.  I am asking purely for fun as I am working through my understanding of general relativity as a retiree's hobby.

Comment: Not sure where you are seeing from your first link, the definition of $\Omega$. Click on the picture that shows the full formula, and work through the frame-dragging part again - It looks like under some parameters will reduce to what you show in the formula in the second link

Comment: Ah!  This is exciting!  You may be solving my problem.  I saw the formula as $$\frac{GI}{c^2R^3} (3\omega *cos(\theta) - \omega))$$ where the angle is zero at the equator and 90 degrees above the pole.  But that is wrong, isn't it?  Is the angle such that rotation above the poles is twice the rate of rotation above the equator?

Comment: Give this a look: arxiv.org/pdf/0802.3346.pdf Pg. 3 and 4 discuss the average frame dragging calculation for GP-B, and also the Lense-Thirring precession of Lageos. I think you may be looking at two different things that are closely related, and trying to equate them, but I need to look into this more myself as I am not an expert at all. Solely from the GP-B page equation though, yes it seems as though precession is $\frac{2GI\omega}{c^2R^3}$ for $\theta=0$ and $\frac{GI\omega}{c^2R^3}$ for $\theta=90$